# complex template composition in Mustache

Tags: templates, template-engine, mustache

Consider a web application that displays the contents of user's refrigerator. Among other things, a list of fruits currently in the fridge needs to be displayed. Each type of fruit needs a very different display. Most importantly, there will be a large number of different fruit types.

I want to implement this using a Mustache template library, but I'm not quite sure what the best approach is.

For starters, here are the templates for each fruit:

```
{{! apple.mustache }}
A {{appleType}} apple from {{groceryStore}}

{{! orange.mustache }}
An orange from {{countryOfOrigin}}

{{! banana.mustache }}
A {{ripeness}} banana

...many more templates here...
```

**Approach 1**

Have a "view model" or "view helper" object prepare the template data by creating a "isBanana"/"isOrange"/etc. key that will be passed to the template. In this case, the fridge template would look something like this:

```
You have the following food in your fridge:

{{#fruits}}
        {{#isApple}}
                {{> apple}}
        {{/isApple}}
        {{#isOrange}}
                {{> orange}}
        {{/isOrange}}
        {{#isBanana}}
                {{> banana}}
        {{/isBanana}}
        ...more conditionals....
{{/fruits}}
```

I've seen this approach recommended several places on the internet. However, I can't see how it will scale: the fridge template must be modified every time a new fruit type is added. It also seems to be going against Mustache's "logic-less" philosophy.

**Approach 2**

Make the view model be responsible for determining the correct template for each fruit type, rendering it, and returning the HTML as data for the template. The fridge template would now look something like:

```
You have the following food in your fridge:

{{{fruits}}}
```

And the view model:

```
class InventoryViewModel
{
    // ...

    function getFruits()
    {
        foreach ($this->fridge->getFruits() as $fruit) {
            if ($fruit instanceof Banana) {
                $html .= $this->mustache->render(...);
            } elseif ($fruit instanceof Apple) {
                $html .= $this->mustache->render(...);
            } else {
                // ...
            }
        }

        return $html;
    }
}
```

The seems better than the first option, but it requires injecting a mustache template rendering object into each view model. I'd like to avoid this coupling, if possible.

**Approach 3**

Use some sort of template composition feature that's not part of the official Mustache specification. (https://github.com/janl/mustache.js/pull/242, https://github.com/mustache/spec/issues/38, etc.).

**Which of these options is the best and why? Am I overlooking something even better?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Probably the simplest is to use a higher-order section (lambda section) in your ViewModel to select your partial for you.

Your base template would look something like this:

```
{{# items }}
  {{# getPartial }}{{ type }}{{/ getPartial }}
{{/ items }}
```

Assuming your fruit has a 'type', of course. Then you'd add a higher-order section for `getPartial`:

```
<?php

class InventoryViewModel
{
    // ...

    function getPartial()
    {
        // you could do string manipulation here,
        // but I prefer the explicitness of a `case`

        return function($tpl, $mustache) {
            switch ($mustache->render($tpl)) {
                case 'Banana':
                    return '{{> banana }}';
                case 'Apple':
                    return '{{> apple }}';
                case 'Orange':
                    return '{{> orange }}';
            }
        };
    }
}
```

In this case, your template remains "logic-free" by moving the logic to its accompanying ViewModel, where it can be unit tested, mocked, and so on.